Label appears above MUI Select instead of inside like a placeholder
I have the following component. I am not sure how to get it to display the label INSIDE the field (like a placeholder). For some reason, it displays it on TOP of the outline.
As you can see from the code, the component is disabled to start with. That's when it's showing the label on TOP of the box.
Once it's enabled and the user clicks into it (without selecting anything), the label comes back to the middle of the field and shows as it's supposed to.
As you can see in the code, I am already setting shrink={false} explicitly and it still doesn't work.
What I actually want is the normal behavior: show the label when nothing is selected (even if it's Select is disabled), and move to the notched position once something is selected.
Here is what I noticed... When I do this in incognito mode, when I first load the page, it works as I would expect it to. However, if I simply hit reload on the page, it jumps to the top again.

'use client';

import TokenChips from '@components/general/TokenChips';
import { Checkbox, FormControl, ListItemText } from '@mui/material';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};

export default function CoisDropdown({
  cois,
  name
}: {
  cois: string[];
  name: string;
}) {
  const [selectedCois, setSelectedCois] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const onCoiSelectChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof selectedCois>) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setSelectedCois(
      // Guard for corner case: on autofill we get a stringified value, so split into array
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value
    );
  };

  // Reset selected cois if new cois are set from parent
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedCois([]);
  }, [cois]);

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mt: 2 }} variant='outlined'>
        <InputLabel id='coi-label' shrink={false}>
          Select COIs
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          fullWidth
          multiple
          labelId='coi-label'
          id={name}
          name={name}
          value={selectedCois}
          onChange={onCoiSelectChange}
          input={
            <OutlinedInput
              label='Select COIs'
            />
          }
          renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(',\u00A0\u00A0')}
          label='Select COIs'
          disabled={cois.length === 0}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {cois.map((coi) => (
            <MenuItem key={coi} value={coi}>
              <Checkbox checked={selectedCois.includes(coi)} />
              <ListItemText primary={coi} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <div style={{ marginTop: '16px' }}>
        <TokenChips tokens={selectedCois} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
 


Here's my solution: Select COIs Label Problem. All I did was remove shrink and label and update the renderValue ever so slightly.
Maybe you can give some more information on what you have? Pictures maybe. It could maybe be a MUI version problem as well?

I did what you showed in the code... Here is what I noticed even before your code. If I remove shrink and open it in an incognito, it shows up just like it's supposed to. However, if I simply hit reload on the page, it jumps to the top again. P.S. I uploaded the picture of what it looks like into the question.

If I wasn't clear, even with what you showed in your code, it goes back up after a refresh of the page

Are you saying that using my code inside of the sandbox is having the label go above the select or in your project it's doing that?

I resolved the issue. The issue was a clear bug in MUI. I upgraded the version and the same code works just fine. Thank you for your help though!
